# Staging to Production without Rebuild

Tags: webpack, environment-variables, production

I have a bundle that was created using webpack in production mode. It is now used for staging. We are talking about static files, `index.html` and `bundle.js`. Now I want to deploy for production, but instead of rebuild another bundle for production, how to efficiently replace only the variables of the current **STAGING** bundle?

For example:

```
// bundle.js
process.env.API_PATH = "api-staging.domain.ext";
console.log(process.env.API_PATH);
// code of the whole project...

// now we want to deploy the same thing to production:
process.env.API_PATH = "api.domain.ext";
console.log(process.env.API_PATH);
// code of the whole project...
```

Now I just don't want to build again just for this minor change.
I want to change just the parameters on the same bundle. Is this possible and how?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the issue without the need of creating the bundle multiple times.
It should be built only once.

Do like so:

Create a folder called "static", better to place it in your root directory of the project. This folder will contain your environment variables file.
This file will be **DIFFERENT** for each environment. Thats means, if you are on local dev you put there local dev configurations. If you are on staging or production you put your content respectively.

Go to your webpack config and add the copy-webpack-plugin:

```
// first install the plugin
npm install --save-dev copy-webpack-plugin

// then configure it on your webpack config
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
new CopyPlugin([
  { from: 'static' },
]),
```

Now basically what going to be happened is that webpack will build your bundle and put it in the dist or what ever your defined to place the bundle.

Then in your index.html file, just before closing the header tag (not body tag) you put this:

```
<script src="env.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

So it will be loaded before the bundle.
Remember, we going to create the production mode bundle only once.

If you are using Html webpack plugin, it will auto generate your index.html and put it in the dist.

Now on every environment the variables will be matched.

---

For webpack dev server to make this working as well, you should use a contentBase pointing to the static folder:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: resolvePath("static")
  },
```

So webpack will grab static contents from there to be using in the dev server.

Answer (score 0):

There are effective libraries for managing environments alongside `webpack` such as:

1. [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)
2. [Default webpack feature for managing multiple environments](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/)

I suggest you, use the second one option to do.

Comment: I have static files that are generated using webpack. I know about dotenv and webpack default environment variables. The problem is that I don't actually run the code using node or webpack, they are just static files! that means that I generate a bundle using webpack, I can set .env file for each environment and build and the bundle will be with all of the variables I need. But I need different variables between staging and production. I dont want to rebuild again for production its a waste..

Comment: So I need to re-build the whole project over again, 99.99% same code, just for changing one line that is different from staging to production?
In staging, my static files are pointing to api-stage.domain.ext.
and in production its api.domain.ext. So for 6 letters I need to burn the CPU again and rebuild a full project again? Sounds very bad. I just need a way to replace the already defined variables and deploy the same bundle and index.html from staging to production. This should be efficient

Comment: I have the same problem you have, and I search a lot but the best and easiest way to do it is rebuilding again. or you can search it in your file and replace with new value whenever you want.